# Should I avoid exposing the Lazy<T> class in public API?

Tags: c#-4.0, architecture, lazy-evaluation

In a design of the public interface of a library, is it legitimate to return an instance of [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) in a property, if I want lazy initialization? Or is it better to always hide the usage of `Lazy<T>` by means of encapsulation or other techniques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the following I'm assumim you mean a Lazy Property.

It depends on the purpose of your interface.

Is it an important detail that the consumer knows that it is lazy ? Or is it just a technical detail which should not change the behavior for the consumer.

It you only have a short delay which must not be handled  by the consumer then i would tend to haide the Lazy and only expose T directly.

If the consumer should be aware and may adapt this behavior then i would expose the lazy .

But thiking on this I would in most cases rather expose a method which indicates that the code may have side effects or may take a while.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to directly expose [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) in the signature. In my use cases, the laziness is an implementation detail.

Don't use this in a property if initialization is long running. In such cases, rather provide a method, considering returning [`Task<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1).