# Should I avoid using the Lazy<T> class if initialization might throw an exception?

Tags: c#-4.0, lazy-initialization

Given that I [expose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31043096/806690) the [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) in a public property. Should I avoid such a design if lazy-initialization might throw an [exogenous exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)?

The exception would be thrown when accessing the `Value` property. And [property getters should not throw exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property). On the other hand, the `Lazy<T>` is crafted and well documented in that area of passing initialization exceptions to the `Value` property getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better in this case to expose a method and let the laziness be an implementation detail.

Don't implement a public property using lazy initialization in case this could throw an exception, for the same reasons as given in the property design guideline.